# Bash script runs fine when called directly, but cron seemingly refuses to run it at all?

Tags: bash, macos, cron

I'm at my wits end with this. I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a nriArray=(newrelic-cli node-newrelic nri-flex helm-charts infrastructure-agent opentelemetry-exporter-java opentelemetry-exporter-go newrelic-lambda-cli newrelic-node-apollo-server-plugin nri-kubernetes nri-prometheus nri-redis infrastructure-bundle newrelic-lambda-layers nri-jmx newrelic-winston-logenricher-node nri-cassandra micrometer-registry-newrelic newrelic-fluent-bit-output nri-kafka node-newrelic-aws-sdk nri-elasticsearch nri-mysql nri-nagios nri-snmp node-newrelic-superagent nri-kube-events nri-mssql newrelic-module-util-java newrelic-logenricher-dotnet aws-log-ingestion newrelic-lambda-tracer-java nri-docker nri-oracledb k8s-metadata-injection nri-discovery-kubernetes nri-haproxy nri-postgresql node-native-metrics nri-consul nri-rabbitmq nri-vsphere nri-winservices nri-ecs newrelic-airflow-plugin newrelic-monolog-logenricher-php node-newrelic-koa nri-f5 aws_s3_log_ingestion_lambda dropwizard-metrics-newrelic k8s-webhook-cert-manager newrelic-fluentd-output nri-couchbase nri-memcached nri-mongodb java-aws-lambda logstash-output-plugin nri-apache nri-varnish java-log-extensions nri-nginx nri-statsd newrelic-opencensus-exporter-go newrelic-opencensus-exporter-python python-agent-extension)
cd /Users/aschneider/NewRelic-OpenSource/

counter=0
while [[ "$counter" -lt "${#nriArray[@]}" ]]; do

    cd "${nriArray[$counter]}"
    git pull &>> /Users/aschneider/NewRelic-OpenSource/cronLog.log
    gsed -i '/Already up to date./d' /Users/aschneider/NewRelic-OpenSource/cronLog.log
    git clean -q -d -f
    cd ..
    ((counter=counter+1))

done

printf "\n\n" >> /Users/aschneider/NewRelic-OpenSource/cronLog.log
holdingVar=$(cat -s /Users/aschneider/NewRelic-OpenSource/cronLog.log) && echo "$holdingVar" > /Users/aschneider/NewRelic-OpenSource/cronLog.log
/Applications/Utilities/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier -message "~/NewRelic-OpenSource/ repositories were updated."
```

The script recursively goes through an array of GitHub repos, pulls in any updates to them, and then moves onto the next folder. It removes any lines stating that the folder is up to date in order to only keep changes in the log file, and then it uses Terminal Notifier to alert me after each update. It works perfectly when I run it with `bash ~/NewRelic-OpenSource/updateOpenSource.sh`, but it doesn't even seem to execute when I put the script in crontab. My `crontab -l` output is below:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
*/30 8-17 * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/bash /Users/aschneider/NewRelic-OpenSource/updateOpenSources.sh
```

I have it running every 30 minutes, from 8am to 5pm, on weekdays. Even if I switch to `* * * * * [command]`, it doesn't do anything, so I don't think it's a scheduling syntax issue. I'm currently running it all on my MacBook, which uses `GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0)`. I've tried adding the PATH definition to the crontab, as well as to the script itself. I've also verified the script is executable with `chmod +x {script}`. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info may be of some help. It's almost always that your PATH is different in your crontab environment VS your terminal session. Good luck.

Comment: Being an old dinosaur, i know little about *"new relics"*, but maybe you want to fill your array with the output of a command... `declare -a nriArray=($(newrelic-cli ...))`

Comment: Also prove to yourself that the most basic cmd works in cron, `* * * * * /bin/date >> /tmp/date_test` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I'll go ahead and look over there as well. I noticed most of these boil down to a PATH issue, but after trying most of the other solutions I'm still not finding a fix. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @shellter I added the `* * * * * /bin/date >> /tmp/date_test` to the crontab, and it does output correctly, so at least I know the cron service is running and is functional.

Comment: Is the script called `updateOpenSource.sh` (your run from commandline) or `updateOpenSources.sh` (crontab entry) ?

Comment: OK, as `/bin/date` is working, I would write `* * * * * { /path/to/your/script opts inputs etc } > /tmp/myScriptLog 2>&1` andd see what shows up there. If a DB process, make sure the access to DB is not blocked because one of the attempts has the system tied up. `ps auxww | grep -E 'myScript|Oracle|Sybase|etc'` is the general idea to see if something is running. Good luck.

Comment: Note also that the output you'll find in that /tmp/ log file, would also appear in the local email queue of the crontab user as separate email messages. GL ;-)

Comment: I suggest you change your cron tab entry to output everything to the log file: `*/30 8-17 * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/bash /Users/aschneider/NewRelic-OpenSource/updateOpenSources.sh > /Users/aschneider/NewRelic-OpenSource/cronLog.log 2>&1`. Then, inside your bash script, just echo everything to stdout/stderrr (e.g. `printf "\n\n"`). At the top of your script, after the hash bang bash line, add `set -x` for debugging/verbose output. See what it's up to.

Comment: The way you're setting the path won't work, you need to export it for the script to pick it up. I'm not sure what your script needs but you might even want to source your profile so a full environment is setup. See this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/cron-ignores-variables-defined-in-bashrc-and-bash-profile

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs run as root by default. You may want to run as the user you would normally run the script as, if you were running the script manually. For example,

`*/5 * * * * (add the username here) sample_executable`

I have also read, but I may be wrong they do not use your PATH variables. So all executables should be fully refrenced before running the script.

Also check the permissions to run the script in crontab.